# ListView: Display data divided into groups?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I would like to display the contents of a DataTable, divided into several groups depending on the value of one of the columns. So, if I have a DataTable (from SQL query) with:

```
GroupID   Name   Description
1         foo    bar
1         one    two
2         some   thing
```

I would like to place all records containing GroupID 1 in one div, all records with GroupID 2 in another div, and so on. How can I do this?

I'm writing in ASP.NET 4.0, with C# codebehind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [LINQ to DataSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386921.aspx) to group your data before databinding.  Something along the lines of

```
var query = from row in myDataTable.AsEnumerable()
            group row by row["GroupID"] // appropriate column access code here
            select row;
```

Then you'll need nested ListViews ([code blatantly copied from here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc500643.aspx)) to actually render it.  Something along the lines of

```
<asp:ListView runat="server" ID="outer" ItemPlaceholderID="PlaceHolder2">
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="PlaceHolder2" /> 
    </LayoutTemplate>

    <ItemTemplate>
        <h1>[Some heading if you'd like one]</h1>

        <asp:ListView runat="server" ID="inner"
          ItemPlaceholderID="PlaceHolder3"
          DataSource="<%# Container.DataItem %>">
          <LayoutTemplate>
            <ul>
              <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="PlaceHolder3" /> 
            </ul>
          </LayoutTemplate>
          <ItemTemplate>
            <!-- data goes here -->
          </ItemTemplate>
      </asp:ListView>
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

Comment: That sounds like something that I want, but I can't for the life of me decipher the "var query = " code. Could you explain?

Comment: @jawonlee: The `var query = ...` is Linq http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa904594.aspx.  There are also some more samples here (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336746.aspx).  Basically Linq is a query syntax that's built into C# 3.  There's a bit more to it than what can be explained in a comment, but there's a lot of good information both on this site and on MSDN on what it is and how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach(DataRow r in myDataTable.Filter("GroupID = 1"))
{
    //write out contents of div1
}

foreach(DataRow r in myDataTable.Filter("GroupID = 2"))
{
    //write out contents of div2
}
```

Comment: Thank you. However, the set of groupIDs changes dynamically, and so does the number of groups I need to display. Is there a way of generating multiple ListViews automatically?

Comment: @jawonlee: Sure, do another query that gets the distinct list of GroupIDs. Then iterarate through that and use each GroupID as your filter criterion in one of the above foreach.